# What is a valid statistical test for comparing data points between two time courses?

Tags: time-series, t-test

I've had conflicting advice over the best way to analyse my time course experiments. I'm comparing cells in two different conditions and observing whether a particular protein accumulates in a certain part of the cell over time. Approximately 50 cells are studied over time for each condition but they don't have the same n number. The average % of cells which are displaying accumulation are then plotted as shown below. I've been told by one person to do a t test and compare each time point individually, whilst somebody else has told me I can't do it this way. Unfortunately they didn't seem able to suggest an alternative! I basically just want to be able to identify which time points are significantly different. 
I'm terrible at stats so extremely simple answers would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Can you post your data? This looks like a small, simple dataset. What are the Ns at each point?

Comment: Hi, yes this is just an example graph which I made up, not my actual data which I don't have access to at the moment.But this accurately reflects the type of distribution I see. The N number for each point is always between 45 to 55. Hope that helps.